# Analysis on $y = x$ line for Equilibria Points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble analyzing what happens when I set the parameters to $(A, B) = (0,0)$ for the phase portrait in reference to this graph below. The first phase portrait graph solutions look undefined, but I wanted to know what it meant terms of the ab graph where $x=a$ and $y=b$. I get that it is on the $a = b$ line, but if we plug in $(a,b) = (3,3)$, then it looks like a source.

In this instance the TRACE is the $a = b$ line, but the phase portrait looks different for when $(a,b)$ is $(0,0)$ versus when $\{a,b > 0 \text{ and } a = b \text{ for } (a,b))\}$.

[image: Graph of ab plane where a = x and b = y]

[image: Phase Portrait when (a,b) = (0,0)]

[image: Phase Portrait when (a,b) = (3,3)]

Comment: dx/dt = Ax + By; dy/dt = -x - y: Where A,B are your parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the system

$$x' = ax + by \\ y'= -x - y$$

The critical point is $(x, y) = (0,0)$

For $a = b = 0$, the eigenvalues of the Jacobian at the critical point are $(-1, 0)$.

Note, the general eigenvalues are

$$\lambda_{1,2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{a^2+2 a-4 b+1}+a-1\right),\dfrac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{a^2+2 a-4 b+1}+a-1\right)$$

If one of the eigenvalues is zero and the other is negative, then the
origin is stable but not asymptotically stable.

We also have a $y'$nullcline as $y = -x$.

Drawing this phase portrait

[image]

If we solve the system $x' = 0, y' = -x-y$, we get

$$\begin{align}x(t) &= c_1 \\ y(t) &= c_2 e^{-t}-c_1 e^{-t} \left(e^t-1\right)\end{align}$$

For the case $a = b = 1$, we have

[image]

For the case $a, b > 0, a = 1, b = 5$, we have

[image]

Comment: What software are you using? I am digging the visual, my Moo.

Comment: I use Mathematica.